# mySQL clearing duplicates in fields

Tags: mysql, unique, distinct

i got a column called "PIDs" which looks like:

"48,162,48,26,19"

Is it possible the clear the duplicates? Like:

"48,162,26,19" ?

Thanks

my SQL Statement looks like:

select id, CIDs, COLOR, XT, MP, Name, concat(PIDs,",",GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id)) as PIDs, IFNULL(Name,id) as unqName from ( 
select id, CIDs, COLOR, XT, MP, Name, concat(PIDs,",",GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id)) as PIDs, IFNULL(MP,id) as unqMP from ( 
select id, CIDs, COLOR, XT, MP, Name, concat(PIDs,",",GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id)) as PIDs, IFNULL(XT,id) as unqXT from ( 
select id, CIDs, COLOR, XT, MP, Name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id) as PIDs, IFNULL(COLOR,id) as unqCOLOR from Produkte group by unqCOLOR 
) m group by unqXT 
) x group by unqMP 
) y group by unqName

Comment: Unrelated note, I wouldn't use a comma for a delimiter in SQL.

Comment: Thanks Rogue for your fast Answer, i could change it to any other delimiter, but i must know, how i could delete duplicates :)

Comment: What Roegue mentioned is not a matter of changing the delimiter but rather changing the design of the database. That table is not even in first normal form as it contains multivalued fields. Check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) form more information

Comment: I think, from this problem, should be clear why normalization is important.

Comment: I have added my SQL Statement to the Question. The result is fine, but i need unique PIDs, anybody know how?